# How to retrieve Wave Source files from Eclipse/Ant tool?

Tags: eclipse, ant, analytics, einstein-analytics, package.xml

I want to retrieve/fetch Wave Source(WaveApplication, WaveDashboard, WaveDataset and etc) files from Eclipse/Ant Migration tool.

I tried many times but not getting any single component file.

I am using Eclipse Neon, Java 1.8 and Force.com IDE 38.0 for Eclipse.
But always getting the warning from Eclipse like, "Package Manifest content warning- The following component type(s) are not supported, so no component will be added to the package manifest editor".

I have updated my Package.xml file to fetch Wave Dataset as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <WaveDataset>
        <application>My_Exploration__app</application>
        <masterLabel>Test Dataset</masterLabel>
    </WaveDataset>
<version>38.0</version>
</Package>
```

Also tried Apache Ant (apache-ant-1.10.1) and Salesforce Ant (salesforce_ant_37.0) for same operation. But not giving any single component file from this too.

Help me to retrieve/fetch Wave artifacts/files.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Use below:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>WaveDataset</name>
</types>
```

You can do same for: WaveApplication, WaveDashboard, WaveDataflow, WaveLens, WaveTemplateBundle, Wavexmd

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk * does not work properly for WaveDataflow and WaveXmd

To retrieve all WaveDataflows you must also include the names of all WaveRecipies

To retrieve all WaveXmds you must also include the names of all WaveDashboards